# Double-click on tab to duplicate

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Since the possibility of duplicating a tab was created, using chrome for research was never so interesting et performant. It help a lot to keep an anchor page before exploring a list of link separetely in new tabs. But "r-clicking" then "opens in a new tab" become quickly a tedious and repetitive task. So why not allowing double-clicking on a tab to duplicate it, or/and a chrome.tabs.onDClicked event ?

Comment: There's no such event. You can post a feature request on https://crbug.com.

Comment: You can also Ctrl + click or middle-click to open a link in a new tab, and it is as fast as a normal click.